# best way to pickup different pandas column value if current column value is blank

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a logic that will pickup a different column value if the current value is blank. Here is what I have so far:

```
df['column1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["column2"] if x["column1"].astype(str)=='' else x["column1"], axis=1)
```

Is there a more efficient way to test for blank/null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `ffill` if values are `nan` (if not replace `''` with `np.nan`)

```
df['column1'] =  df['column1'].ffill(df['column2'])
```